# How to get the headline an element belongs to

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I can use `org-element-context` on a, e.g., link on the page and walk up the parents to see which paragraph it belongs to. However, I'd like to get the value of the header the paragraph/link is under. Is there a sane way to do this? I'm new to the org-mode AST, so any general tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what information you need out of the heading:

If you just want the text of the heading, you can use `org-get-heading`.  (EDIT: This function appears to have been added somewhere between Org versions 8.2.10 and 8.3.2.)  Note that this function returns a *propertized* text string (see [this manual entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Props-and-Strings.html) for more information, but for most purposes, you can ignore the text properties and just treat it as a string).

If you want the position of heading, I (surprisingly) can't find anything that just gives you that out of the box.  I'd do something like this:

```el
(defun my/org-back-to-heading-safe (&optional invisible-ok)
  "As `org-back-to-heading', but return nil before first heading."
  (condition-case err
      (org-back-to-heading invisible-ok)
    (error nil)))

(defun my/org-get-heading-pos ()
  "Return position of heading containing point.
If before the first heading of the buffer, return nil.
Do not move point."
  (save-excursion (my/org-back-to-heading-safe :invisible-ok)))
```

If you want the full list like `org-element-context`, you can do something similar:

```el
(defun my/org-element-heading ()
  "Return context for heading containing point.
As `org-element-context', if point is on a heading.  Otherwise,
return the value `org-element-context' would return if point were
on its heading.

If before the first heading of the buffer, return nil."
  (save-excursion
    (when (my/org-back-to-heading-safe :invisible-ok)
      (org-element-context))))
```

Comment: I'm on 8.3.2.  I'll add that to the answer, too.

Comment: Will verify once I figure out my emacspath issue (emacs for Mac OSX seems to set some paths, but at some point look at the paths I load in my init.el, and sorting it out isn't fun). Thank you!

Comment: This works! Finally figured out where my path loading issue was and tested this out. Do you know how to get the actual header text out of the object `org-get-heading` returns?

Comment: That's just a [string with text properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Props-and-Strings.html).  You can probably just ignore the properties and treat it as the actual header text, and if you need to strip them you can use `set-text-properties`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! New to non-trivial emacs scripting.

Comment: Of course.  And for what it's worth, I had to look it up too, as I didn't recognize the `#()` read syntax.  I'll add this to the answer in case it confuses anyone else.